# Updating Android Display with automatic counter

Tags: android

this might be a noob question. I just started android programming. I want my app to display a counter from 0 to 10, with 1 second delay between each count. The app will start at 1, after a delay of 1 second, it will display 2. Can anyone help me with a sample program? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    TextView timer;
    int i;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    timer = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTimer);
    for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
    new AsyncTimer().execute();


    class AsyncTimer extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
    timer.setText(i.toString());
    }
            }
```

Just a solution that came out of my head.